# Eclipse problem - file stayed opened in editor causes problematic eclipse startup

Tags: eclipse

Worked in Eclipse. 
I closed it without closing file i was working on.

On next start eclipse blocked - file inside could not be opened and 
it looked like it will load an load forever

Is there a way to close file in editor before eclipse is started
or do some kind of clean so i dont have this starting problem.

thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file is still being treated as opened by the OS's file system.
In this case restart your computer and everything should be ok.

**EDIT:** well in that case it has something to do with your eclipse induced settings (eigth user settings, but is uspect it is the lock-file). Have a look into the folder (windows explorer) whre your file is to be found. Make sure you see hidden files too. Then go into the folde **.metadata** and have a look into the file **.lock . What is in it?**